# can we get data in google docs to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, google-docs

I have data in google spreadsheets. Now I need to import that data into my database `MYSQL`. I have seen that it can be done by using `JDBC`. I think `JDBC` is for `java`, but I need it in `php`. How to workout on this. Please suggest me some tips

Comment: Google have an API for this, take a look: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: In this I didnt get how to import into db